# SQL how to return a value only if occurs more than 2 times

Tags: mysql, sql

so I basically I have a table called "teams" it contains the team name and team id. I also have another table called players, most players are linked to a team with a column called teamID. So what I need is an SQL query that returns all the teams that have 2 or more players linked to it. From what I understand this cant be done with 1 query. 
So what I would like to do is to return each teamID and the number of times it appears in the table. How would I do this?

So then my second query would only select the teamID that occurs 2 times or more

Teams table:

```
|id|teamName|
|1 |scorpions|
|2 |dragons  |
```

Players Table:

```
|id|teamID|name|
|1 |1     |mark|
|2 |1     |rob|
|3 |2     |bob|
```

So what I need at the end is the whole teams table minus the teams with less than 2 players assigned to them

So for the sample data It should only return:

```
|id|teamName|
|1 |scorpions|
```

Comment: This can easily be done with a single query.  What have you tried?  Provide sample data and desired results as well.

Comment: Are you familiar with `HAVING` clause?

Comment: I updated the post to have sample data and a sample anwser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in one query:

```
select t.id as team_id, t.teamName, 
       count(p.id) as player_count
from teams t
join players p on p.teamId = t.id
group by t.id, t.teamName
having count(p.id) > 1
```

Join the tables, group by the teams and take only those teams having more than 1 player.

Comment: nvm I fixed it there was an extra space in the query between count and the () thank you for your help